# Javascript object list. take a name and a list, then return list of all names etc function

Tags: javascript, object

I've been trying to figure out what's the best code to make for this function, but the codes i'd tried isn't working.

Here are the instructions.

- Should take a name and a list of people,and return a list of all the names that  is not friends with", function use isFriends irrirate each object if comes back false that is on the friend list

  ```
  var data = [
    {name: "Jimmy", friends:["Sara", "Liza"]},
    {name: "Bob", friends:[]},
    {name: "Liza", friends: ["Jimmy"]},
    {name: "Sara", friends: ["Jimmy"]}
  ];

  assert.deepEqual(nonFriends("Jimmy", data), ["Bob"]);
  assert.deepEqual(nonFriends("Bob", data), ["Jimmy", "Liza", "Sara"]);
  assert.deepEqual(nonFriends("Sara", data), ["Bob","Liza"]);
  ```

this is my code for isFriends function

- `isFriend()` : Should take a name and an object and return true if  is a friend of  and false otherwise"

  ```
  function isFriend(name, obj) {
    if(Array.isArray(obj.friends) && obj.hasOwnProperty("friends")) {
      for(var i = 0; i < obj.friends.length; i++) {
        if(name === obj.friends[i]) {
          return true;  
        }
      }    
    }  
   return false;   
  }
  ```

how do i create a nonFriend function as described to implement isFriend function. can you also explain it to me in details. i'm not confident on if else statements and etc. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The nonFirends() method include the following things to do:

1. Extract all people name.
2. Find if the input name is a name in the list, if not that means all people are not friends.
3. Compare the friend list of the target object with the full list of
   names.

**The following code should work.**

```
function nonFriends(name, arr){
    var nameList = [];
    var result = [];
    var current = null;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(name === arr[i].name){
            current = arr[i];
        }else{
            nameList.push(arr[i].name);
        }
    }

    if(current === null){
        return nameList;
    }

    for(var i=0; i<nameList.length; i++){
        if(current.friends.indexOf(nameList[i]) == -1){
            result.push(nameList[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: what's the best way to understand, create, read, etc etc for javascript.
i've tried studying from reading materials, watched youtube clips, etc etc.
when it comes to doing the exercises i still have to look up what code to use and how to use them. is there any method u can recommend? i am currently enrolled in a bootcamp for javascript. tomorrow i start my 3rd week, but i'm having a difficult time.

Comment: @kenwin Look up a guide on how to create something interesting. Follow along with the guide, make changes/improvements to it. Repeat.

Comment: I personally didn't study any course for javascript. Just keep practicing. It is just like doing Maths. You can have multiple solutions to a question, just don't afraid wrong or not the best solution. Sometimes I just keep trying different solution until I get the right one.

Comment: if and else statements, comparison, true/false. i have issue in those area. how do you guys remember javascript codes when creating functions. when i get stuck i blank thats when i over think too much. thank guys for the advice!